# How to get PK fields after call save()

Tags: python, django

I'm a little tricky with the new version of Django, the idea is to make an instance before you save and get the id or pk I repeat field without saving.

```
class User(models.Model):
    .....
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        I'm need instance of user for access first self.pk
        """
        self.slug = self.get_slug(self.pk)
        return super(User, self).save()
```

The problem is still not defined "self.pk" alone will do it until you call save() that is until it is saved, the idea is to know how can I have the "self.pk" without saving earlier.

I think it could do so, but there is something wrong or not doing well, any ideas?

```
# My idea
def save(self, *ars, **kwargs):
    instance = super(User, self).save()
    self.slug = self.get_slug(self.pk)
    return instance
```

Any idea?, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `self` parameter is the instance of User you want to access.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.username  # This is username of the 
    self.slug  # This is user instance slug value
    super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

*I would make a comment but i dont have enough rep.*

I assume you have a slug field which must be unique?
And you want to use the id(default django pk) to populate it?
The django id field is [AutoField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.AutoField) witch gets the value when saved so you cant use it before you save the object.

A hack-around:

```
# save in the model
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # get_timestamp should return a string with the current time --> unique
    self.slug = get_timestamp()
    super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    self.slug = self.get_slug(self.pk)
    super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13891070/3974427) an example for a timestamp string. Read the Python docs about datetime, calendar and date if you want to make your own.