# How can I count time in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

I want a code that shows the complete time someone has been in a voice channel, but I don't know how to start and stop a counter.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(before, after):

    if after.voice.voice_channel:
        timestrr = time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y-%H:%M:%S")
        voicezeit(after.id, timestrr)
#here should a timer start
    else:
         #and here should the timer stop
```

Comment: I want the timer to start at A and stop at B and then record the time

Comment: You want to keep showing a timer of how long it has been since someone has been on a channel? Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13890935/does-pythons-time-time-return-the-local-or-utc-timestamp not help?

Comment: Why not just use `time.time()` to record the time at point A and B?

Comment: Exactly - and take B-A as time in seconds and divide by 60 and 60*60 accordingly to get minutes and hours

Comment: You subtract the start time [A] from the end time [B].

Answer (score 53):

If you just want to measure the elapsed wall-clock time between two points, you could use time.time():

```
import time

start = time.time()
print("hello")
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

This gives the execution time in seconds.

> Another option since 3.3 might be to use `perf_counter` or `process_time`,
>   depending on your requirements. Before 3.3 it was recommended to use
>   `time.clock` . However, it is currently deprecated:

On Unix, return the current processor time as a floating point number expressed in seconds. The precision, and in fact the very definition of the meaning of “processor time”, depends on that of the C function of the same name.

On Windows, this function returns wall-clock seconds elapsed since the first call to this function, as a floating point number, based on the Win32 function `QueryPerformanceCounter()`. The resolution is typically better than one microsecond.

Deprecated since version 3.3: The behaviour of this function depends on the platform: use perf_counter() or process_time() instead, depending on your requirements, to have a well defined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need a counter? Just initialise `start_time` variable to `None` in the beginning, then in your if-block you check whether it is set, if it isn't you set it to `time.time()`. In the else-block set `end_time` to `time.time()` again and calculate the difference.

**EDIT**

I don't know what the layout of the rest of your application, you have to initialise `start_time = None` somewhere outside of this update function. You would need to set it for each user, I will assume it is stored as `user.start_time`, but again, this is dependent on the structure of your app. Then your function could become this:

```
    @bot.event
    async def on_voice_state_update(before, after):

        if after.voice.voice_channel:
            if not user.start_time:  # this was set to None somewhere else
                user.start_time = time.time()
            # import datetime from datetime at the top of your file
            timestrr = datetime.from_timestamp(user.start_time).strftime("%d.%m.%Y-%H:%M:%S")
            voicezeit(after.id, timestrr)
        else:
             end_time = time.time()
             voice_chat_time = end_time - after.user.start_time
```

Comment: 1 problem I have when using time.time()  is that I have to import time from time and when I do that the timestrr function doesnt work no more

Comment: That's because `strftime` is a datetime function. If you need to use it, you can import `datetime` instead and set your variables to `datetime.datetime.now()`.

Comment: Sorry, the `time` module does have `strftime` but it only works with the current time. You could also use both `time.time()` and `datetime.datetime.from_timestamp(start_time).strftime("%d.%m.%Y-%H:%M:%S")` to get the string.

Comment: it thros me out this error "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'start_time' referenced before assignment"

Comment: Yes, you need to assign `start_time` first. I will update my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: If you edit your question to provide some more context, I'm happy to update my answer again. You probably want to set `start_time` when you set `voice_state.voice.voice_channel = True` from the bit I can gather.