# Perform range query on sqlite datetime column or on string column(which having dateTime)

Tags: c#, sqlite, datetime, .net-3.5

net.dll for performing operations on sqlite. i am facing issue for sqlite database like i am created column as Text name as DateTime and storing date string into it. i want entries which are in between some date range, but i am not able to execute query.

used query for type of DateTime Column as "Date":
**

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ColumnName BETWEEN '1800-1-1' AND '2010-12-12'
```

**

used query for type of DateTime Column as "String":

**

```
SELECT * FROM MD5_HEADER WHERE Sent BETWEEN '4/1/2007 12:01:00 AM' AND '12/1/2010 4:05:36 AM'
```

**

if anyone having solution regarding this issue please help me.

(c#, Sqlite.net.dll, framework3.5)

Answer (score 1):

Try filling the gaps with zeros:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ColumnName BETWEEN '1800-01-01' AND '2010-12-12'
```

Answer (score 0):

First, SQLite doesn't have a `date` type. It stores dates as either `text` or  `integer`.
The first query looks correct assuming your column is of type `text` since ISO 8061 formatted dates have lexicographical order. It just looks like your missing a semicolon at the end of the statement.

Comment: But it checks based on string hence result shows wrong value.
and main how to add datetime format in sqlite. (using c#)
Because it does not accept dateTime.ToString() as a input for dateTime

Comment: Assuming a column type defined as `TEXT` all you need to do is provide a ISO formatted date string. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114983/given-a-datetime-object-how-do-i-get-a-iso-8601-date-in-string-format. There's example code in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099845/datetimes-and-net-with-sqlite demonstrating how to insert a row in to a table with a datetime column.