# Android SQL DATETIME CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

In my android application I have a datetime field with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as default value. The problem is that it is inserting different value then the emulator's time.

- How to insert current date and time of the device.
- Can I use this column to sort the table or delete records older
  the 24 hours.

Here is my code:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
   String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_BLOCKEDSMS + " (" +
            COLUMN_BLOCKEDSMS + " TEXT," +
            COLUMN_DATETIME + "DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);";
    db.execSQL(query);
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give an example of the value that's being inserted for a particular time in the emulator? And what timezone is your emulator set to? (i.e., are you sure your problem isn't [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381371/sqlite-current-timestamp-is-in-gmt-not-the-timezone-of-the-machine)?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `DATETIME DEFAULT (datetime('now','localtime'))` will do what you want and will be sortable it is stored as/like **2017-01-12 07:33:10**.

i.e.

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
   String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_BLOCKEDSMS + " (" +
            COLUMN_BLOCKEDSMS + " TEXT," +
            COLUMN_DATETIME + "DATETIME DEFAULT (datetime('now','localtime')));";
    db.execSQL(query);
}
```

As per the comments the part of the statement *COLUMN_DATETIME + "DATETIME DEFAULT (datetime('now','localtime')));* is explained as follows:-

**COLUMN_DATETIME** is the name of the column, **DATETIME** is the type of the column (noting that SQLite does not have rigid types [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) ). **DEFAULT** indicates the default value to be used (optional).

If the value is explicit e.g 0 'A' etc, then the value simply follows DEFAULT. However, if the value is calculated via an expression then it must be enclosed in brackets *()*. SQLite has numerous functions of which 5 are date and time functions. These are **date**, **time**, **datetime**, **julianday** and **strftime**.

Either **datetime** or **strftime** could be used, although datetime was chosen for this example/solution. So hence we have `... DEFAULT ( datetime(<argumnets>))` *where  haven't as yet been explained.*

The syntax for **datetime** is `datetime(timestring, modifier, modifier, ...)`. Timestring being the time (inclusion of date allowed). **now** generates a time timestring according to the current datetime. However, it is UTC. The **localtime** modifer, modifies the time according to local time (NOTE assuming that the timestring is UTC with caveat of *unpredictable results* if not).

Further and more detailed information can be found here [SQL As Understood By SQLite - Date And Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot. it worked. can you explain "datetime('now','localtime')".