# flask postgresql ERROR: syntax error at or near "

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

i'm new to flask and dev in general this error is so subjective i can't google even after seeing couple of posts on stackoverflow i couldnt figure it out everything correct and literally i'm pulling my hair

```
@app.route("/bookPage/<all>" , methods=["GET" , "POST"])
def bookPage(all):
    global all2
    if request.method == "POST":

        #variables
        list1 = ['101','milk','3','jack','2018-09-27 16:33:58.553349' ]

        db.execute("INSERT INTO review_table (id, review, rate , user , time_t) VALUES (:id, :review, :rate , :user , :time_t)" , {"id" : list1[0], "review" : list1[1], "rate": list1[2] ,"user":list1[3] , "time_t" :list1[4] })
        db.commit()
        print( f"review has been added of value : ,{review} \n ,and rate of :  , { rate_i} ,\n , by user : , { user_i }, \n, and Id : , {id_i}" )
    else:

        print("\n\n",all,"\n\n")
        all1 = all.split(",")
        all2 =[a.strip("()").replace("'","") for a in all1]




    return render_template("bookPage.html",all1=all2)
```

everytime i excute it i get this error ( ERROR:  syntax error at or near "user" ) he points on the "user" in

```
"INSERT INTO review_table (id, review, rate , user , time_t)
```

everything correct i'm nw but i have done the db execute many times

table in db is empty postgresql of columns

Column  Type    Comment

- id   integer
- review   character varying NULL
- rate integer NULL
- user character varying NULL
- time_t   time without time zone NULL

  please let me know why is this keep happening
  i've changed user input with constant string "test" i got the same error ...
  i think the error is misleading

Comment: The error is exact: your column list contains the key word `user`. If you wish to use identifiers that collide with key words, you will have to use quoted identifiers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let your database fill the field with time and date, add to your `CREAT TABLE` this:

`time_t time without time zone DEFAULT current_timestamp`

And in your `INSERT` do not use time_t:

```
    db.execute("INSERT INTO review_table (id, review, rate , user ) VALUES (:id, :review, :rate , :user )" , {"id" : list1[0], "review" : list1[1], "rate": list1[2] ,"user":list1[3] })
```

You can find other variants of this solution: [Sqlite: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is in GMT, not the timezone of the machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381371/sqlite-current-timestamp-is-in-gmt-not-the-timezone-of-the-machine)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the values to the right type before sending them to the database.

```
    user_i = ''
    rate_i = request.form.get("rate", type=int)
    user_i = session['user']
    time_i = datetime.now()
    id_i = int(all2[0])

    db.execute("INSERT INTO review_table (id, review, rate , user , time_t) VALUES (?, ?, ? , ? , ?)" , (id_i, review_i, rate_i , user_i , time_i ))
```

Comment: id_i = int(all2[0]) ,  rate_i = request.form.get("rate", type=int) , i replaced both but it didnt work , same error - ERROR: syntax error at or near "user" --- what i should convert time_i to ?

Comment: you need to convert time too. to utc datetime.