# How to output timestamp in localtime?

Tags: sql, linux, sqlite

This is related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381371/sqlite-current-timestamp-is-in-gmt-not-the-timezone-of-the-machine). The Unix Epoch timestamp `1687303606` equates to `2023-06-20 23:26:46 UTC`. I want to output it in my local time, UTC-4 or Eastern Daylight Saving Time (EDT). In SQLite3 if I do :

```
select datetime(1687303606, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')
```

it still outputs `2023-06-20 23:26:46`, not `2023-06-20 19:26:46`. FYI:

```
$ sqlite3 --version
3.42.0 2023-05-16 12:36:15 831d0fb2836b71c9bc51067c49fee4b8f18047814f2ff22d817d25195cf350b0

$ date
Tue Jun 20 19:58:06 EDT 2023
```

Comment: It works for me. Are you sure the machine you are testing on has a local time setting different from UTC?

Comment: That's why I included the output of the date command in my post. It shows the local time in EDT (Eastern Daylight Time).

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](https://sqlite.org/forum/info/e8d9927415cc29f58efbdd80f50ecf11f1f9ace20c241080af60b80ad2334eb4), your problem probably lies in your OS implementation of time zones (the thread is about cygwin but it could be an issue on other OS).

Try to unset the TZ environment variable.

Comment: TZ is already unset in my shell, but thanks for the suggestion.